# Changing address of MPU 9250 connected to ESP32

Tags: esp32, imu

Can I change the I2C address of a device (MPU9250) connected to ESP 32 using int pin. I understand that in arduino board if we connect the int pin to A0 the default I2C address of MPU 9250 changes from 0x68 to 0x69. Is something similar possible with ESP 32? Which Pin I should connect to?

Comment: you are misunderstanding how A0 pin is used ... if it is connected to GND then the address is 0x68 ... if it is connected to Vcc then the address is 0x69 .... your question is not about the arduino, so it is off topic here

Answer (score 1):

You have only two choices with this device on an I2C bus.  As stated in the datasheet:

[image: MPU9250 Datasheet I2C Bus]

So it's either:

1. 0b1101000
2. 0b1101001

The AD0 pin selects which of these two addresses are used.

The complete datasheet can be viewed at the following link as well as other places:

[Datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/TDK%20PDFs/MPU-9250_Rev_1.1.pdf)